# Error with add user in a group using Add-MsolGroupMember

Tags: powershell, azure, office365

I am trying to add user in a group but I am getting error:

```
Add-MsolGroupMember -GroupObjectId $group1.ObjectId -GroupMemberType "User" -GroupMemberObjectId 077cf65b-4b9f-44e4-9f34-6c96a063a0df
```

[image: error message]

Comment: It tells you the problem in the error... Use Add-DistributionGroupMember https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124340(v=exchg.160).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As bunzab said, we should use `Add-DistributionGroupMember` to add member.

First, we should **connect** to exchange online powershell:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

After that, we can use this powershell to add member, like this:
[image]
[image]

More information about connect to exchange online powershell, please refer to this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj984289(v=exchg.160).aspx).

Comment: Does this work for you? please let me know if you would like further assistance.